# AS88 Assembly Language source file editing

Tags: assembly, x86-16, as88

I first want to ask, is Stackoverflow a proper place to find answers about AS88 assembly language? if not can someone please direct me to a more beneficial place?

I'm going to post my question just in case:

I have to edit the following source code so that it skips the first two pairs of vector numbers in the inner production calculation. I'm not sure what that means, and here is my code, if someone can explain or help my answer this i'd appreciate it.

```
! This program multiplies two vectors
! It shows a subroutine with arguments and
! a local variable. See section 9.8.3.
_EXIT   = 1              !  1
_PRINTF = 127            !  2
.SECT .TEXT              !  3
inpstart:                !  4
    MOV  BP,SP       !  5
    PUSH vec2        !  6
    PUSH vec1        !  7
    MOV CX,vec2-vec1 !  8
    SHR  CX,1        !  9
    PUSH CX          ! 10
    CALL vecmul      ! 11
    MOV  (inprod),AX ! 12
    PUSH AX          ! 13
    PUSH pfmt        ! 14
    PUSH _PRINTF     ! 15
    SYS              ! 16
    ADD  SP,12       ! 17
    PUSH 0           ! 18
    PUSH _EXIT       ! 19
    SYS              ! 20

vecmul:                  ! 21
    PUSH BP          ! 22
    MOV  BP,SP       ! 23
    MOV  CX,4(BP)    ! 24
    MOV  SI,6(BP)    ! 25
    MOV  DI,8(BP)    ! 26
    PUSH 0           ! 27
1:      LODS             ! 28
    MUL  (DI)        ! 29
    ADD  -2(BP),AX   ! 30
    ADD  DI,2        ! 31
    LOOP 1b          ! 32
    POP  AX          ! 33
    POP  BP          ! 34
    RET              ! 35

.SECT .DATA              ! 36
pfmt: .ASCIZ "The in product is %d!\nThe sum is !"! 37
.ALIGN 2                 ! 38
vec1:   .WORD 3,4,7,11,3 ! 39
vec2:   .WORD 2,6,3,1,0  ! 40
.SECT .BSS               ! 41
inprod: .SPACE 2         ! 42
```

Comment: You can ask the question to the 'Code Review' Community

Comment: @Coding4Fun : This isn't a code review question. They are asking how to make a particular alteration to this code.

Comment: Are you taking a course using as88 ?

Comment: @FareenC if you do post there, please ensure your question is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for that site - i.e. it is **working** code that **you** maintain.

Comment: @michaelPetch yes i am using as88.

Comment: Have you asked your professor or teacher assistant to understand what the question is asking?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Still, it's the Code review ( make a particular alteration ..)

Comment: @Coding4Fun : You must be new to software engineering, and probably haven't read the criteria for asking a question on Code Review Stack Exchange. Code Reviews *are not* designed to change code into something else with different functionality. A review is to take existing code and find bugs, and or find improvements (performance; code quality; meeting  coding standards; etc). This question is off topic for Code Review Stack Exchange because this code doesn't currently do what the OP needs.

Comment: I have modified your question to be an AS88 question, not a MASM question as AS88 and MASM are different (including different syntax)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have asked but unfortunately they are not available right now nor have they answered my emails.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code does take two vectors, and calculates their product.

```
vec1:   [  3,  4,  7, 11,  3]
vec2:   [  2,  6,  3,  1,  0]

result = 3*2 + 4*6 + 7*3 + 11*1 + 3*0 = 62
```

(dare you verify by running your current code?)

So by:

> it skips the first two pairs of vector numbers

I would understand this calculation (for the same vectors):

```
result = 7*3 + 11*1 + 3*0 = 32
```

The `3*2` and `4*6` pairs skipped.

You can modify your current code by adjusting the `vecmul` subroutine to some `vecmul_2pairskip` subroutine, which will take same arguments as current.

Then you may check if the size of vectors is 3+ (i.e. `sub cx,2` and return with 0 result when `cx <= 0` after adjustment - probably use completely separate exit branch of code, as the usage of stack makes it prone to mistakes when skipping whole calculation loop). Or if you know the arguments will be only those hard-coded vector data of size 5, then there's no need to test the adjusted vector size.

Then skip the first two values of each vector (`si` and `di` points to the first element of each vector, so you have to advance them both by 2*2 = 4 (2 elements, and `WORD` size is 2).

The remaining product calculation in loop can stay as is, no change needed.

Comment: Change isn't strictly *needed*, but the current loop is pretty horrible.  It uses an accumulator on the stack!  But BX is free.  Another alternative would be to keep an end-pointer in memory so the loop-termination condition would be `cmp si, [bp-2]` / `jb`, so the memory operand is read-only.

Comment: How would i be able to create something like a global variable or something in order to add all the numbers together? like in this case I would get 40 and print that out along with the product message?  would this be in the vecmul section?

Comment: @FareenC you don't understand that code you posted, at all, I guess? Then hire a programmer, if you don't know to code. Or just don't do tasks you are not capable of. If this was some school task, then you are very likely supposed to understand that code, so get some book about assembly, your lectures information, etc... and spend few months with them. Then return back to this code.  (the current code does use "global" `inprod` for storing result, within `vecmul` it doesn't use any globals, only local stack memory).